# Why aren't the view tabs showing when my View is the selected view?

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I made a View plugin for Jenkins:

```
public class PipelineDashboard extends View {
     ...
}
```

And made my resources/my.package.PipelineDashboard package with the `configure-entries.jelly` and `main.jelly` files.

Here's my `configure-entries.jelly` file:

```
 <j:jelly xmlns:j="jelly:core" xmlns:st="jelly:stapler" xmlns:d="jelly:define" xmlns:l="/lib/layout" xmlns:t="/lib/hudson" xmlns:f="/lib/form">
     <div class="myViewContent">...</div>
 </j:jelly>
```

The plugin works great and behaves exactly how I want it except one problem: when I create a view (in the image "**Bacon**") of my custom view and that view is the selected view, the tabs for selecting the other tabs goes away:

[image: Missing tabs]

Reference that to having the default `All` tab selected:

[image: All has tabs]

Is there something I need to put in my Jelly file or in my View extension to make that show up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it:

In `main.jelly` for your View add the following at the top:

```
    <j:set var="views" value="${it.owner.views}"/>
    <j:set var="currentView" value="${it}"/>
    <st:include page="viewTabs.jelly" it="${it.owner.viewsTabBar}"/>
```